# What does "For my rest" mean?

Tags: meaning

I am trying to read an English picture book to my daughter, but cannot understand this phrase "For my rest". The title of the book is *Hattie helps out* by Jane Godwin & Davina Bell. The phrase in question is used like this:

> 'When you've finished that, it's time for your sleep, Hattie.'
>   'For my rest,', said Hattie. 'I'm too old for a sleep in the afternoon...

Could someone please explain the meaning of the phrase?

Comment: Hi Tomo, welcome to our site. When asking a question, it's expected that you show evidence of your own research. For example, what is the dictionary definition of *rest*? Is there a meaning that's similar to *sleep*? Armed with that information, do you still have a question? If yes, please [edit] it to add the necessary detail. See [ask] for further guidance. :-)

Comment: I find the phrasing of original sentence strange. It would make more sense to me if it were: *When you've finished that, it* ***will be*** *time for* ***you to*** *sleep*. But, that aside, it sounds like a play on *sleep* being a long event that starts at bedtime, and *rest* (like *nap*) being just a short event. Or possibly it's not the length of time being referenced, but a commentary on adults not falling asleep at all in the afternoon. (Which is a strange message, since many people do function better with afternoon naps—assuming they can get them.)

Comment: In any case, I don't think dictionary definitions are going to help without more context. (Or possibly it's just open to interpretation.)

Comment: @JasonBassford Have you never come across 'sleep' meaning 'a period of sleep'?

Comment: @KateBunting Yes. But normally it's in the past tense, the indefinite article is used, and there's some kind of adjective involved. *I had a good sleep.* So, at least in terms of how I've heard it used, I find it odd (although not wrong) to have been used in this way.

Answer (score 4):

Young children are sometimes encouraged to take a short [period of] sleep in the afternoon. Hattie evidently considers that she is too old to need to go to sleep at that time, but prefers to call it a 'rest'. 'For my rest' is just correcting what her mother said.